# Rsync --progress parameter syntax error

Tags: ubuntu, rsync

when i try to use rsync with --progress or -P option (--progress --partial) i get an error saying:

```
Unknown --info item: "flist"
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at options.c(453) [client=3.1.2]
```

I'm using ubuntu 18.04, uninstalled and reinstalled rsync but problem still persists. Example command:

```
rsync -avzP /home/test/testdir /home/test/testdir2/
```

or

```
rsync -avz --partial --progress /home/test/testdir /home/test/testdir2/
```

Comment: Both your examples work for me, rsync version 3.1.0.

Comment: I found [this](https://forum.linuxmint.net.tr/index.php?topic=5917.0), indicating it could be a permission issue. How did you create the directories (as user or root)? What user tries to rsync the files?

Comment: You you have a `.popt` file in your home directory? Show its contents if so. Have you determined if it is the `--partial` or the `--progress` option, or only the combination? Note also that `-z` option is useless on a local transfer.

Comment: @eblock Directories are mine and permissions are correct. Trying it with sudo gives the same error.

Comment: @wurtel no .popt file in my home dir. --partial works, --progress doesn't. -P automatically doesn't work too.

Comment: No point using `z` flag; it's ignored on local-to-local copies. Also, I think you may mean `rsync ... /home/test/testdir/ /home/test/testdir2` (I've moved the trailing slash to the source).

Comment: Result of `type rsync`, please.

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same problem, but it was resolved by adding `LC_ALL=C` before of the `rsync` command on the command line.

This confirms [O.Yavuz' thesis about localization](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/505026/116858) (my computer also has Turkish system language).

Answer (score 2):

It's most probably because of your localization settings. Set Ubuntu's language to English, and country to US (maybe not necessary) and --progress option miraculously will start working.

Edit: "most probably" because I had same problem on my Raspberry Pi running Raspbian which is also Debian based as Ubuntu. I fixed the problem by changing system language from Turkish to English and country to US. But I don't have Ubuntu to try so I had to make an assumption here.

Comment: “most probably”? Can you explain how / why that might be related, or give a reference that supports your answer? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.